# Ubuntu 18.04 / Nvidia GeForce GTS 450 / 4k howto?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution, opengl

Does anyone know how to run an Nvidia GeForce GTS 450 in 4k mode under Ubuntu 18.04?

Since today I own a 4k monitor, but Ubuntu lets me only show 1920x1080 pixels.

By the way: Installing different drivers of Nvidia (384, 390, 430) shot my OpenGL driver. No way to use blender any more.

Does any one know, which drivers and libs are relevant to run

a) 4k (over HDMI)

b) Nvidia GeForce GTS 450

c) openGL

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about 4K resolution hardware support? Nvidia 450 — 2010 year. https://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gts-450/specifications

Comment: Not really sure. The Website "nvidia.com" is a bit wired. The card should be able to show 3840x2160, but is painted RED. So I don't really know if it supports 4k.

Comment: And anyway. If someone knows, that Nvidia 450 does not support 4K. Any ideas for a newer card? Mostly we user blender, gimp, freecad and kdenlive. If it comes to gaming, we only play 0ad, which works fine on older hardware.

Comment: I see only «Maximum Digital Resolution
2560x1600» in GTS 450 specifications. What about new cards: Nvidia GT 1030 is cheap product and much powerfully than GTS 450. It has support 4K resolution «7860x4320».